# How to arrange months properly in ArcGIS dashboard

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, date

I am trying to edit my category selector for month in ArcGIS dashboard as it is displaying the months alphabetically instead of January, February, March and so on. How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without seeing the data, but I would guess that your "month" field is just a string, as opposed to an actual **datetime**.

Unless your `month` field was a coded domain of integers, or there were a corresponding field like `month_number` in your layer, there's no way for a **Category Selector** to automatically sort them by date, since it doesn't know these are dates.

What you need to do instead is use the **Defined Values** option and manually put in each month. Then your selector will keep the order in which your options are defined. Since there are only twelve months, this is easy and quick.

[image: defined values]